# WinForm Conversion To Wpf

Tags: wpf, winforms

Can I Convert my whole WinForm Application to wpf application?. I wants to convert my Accounting Software to Wpf Is it possible?.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No - there is no direct translation from Windows Forms to WPF - in addition, doing this directly would be poor, and lead to a very poorly designed WPF application.

I discuss this in depth in [my series on WPF with MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) - in particular, ["Part 3"](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/11/24/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-3-our-application-in-wpf/) shows what happens when you write WPF using the same manner as typical Windows Forms applications, but then I go onto show why this is a bad idea in general.

WPF, at its core, is built upon a very different programming paradigm than Windows Forms.   It would be better to separate out your business logic in Windows Forms, then write a new View layer in WPF to work with the logic.

Comment: +1 for the different paradigm. I wrote a silverlight app just like a windows forms app and having so much trouble updating it because UI and logic and all stuck together. Since then I truly understand the value of MVVM.

Comment: What you think about third party tools or software for conversion?

Comment: @mahesh: I'd recommend reading my series at: http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/  You'll find that, even if you do find a 3rd party solution that will convert, the conversion will, in general, be worse than useless - you're better off doing it manually.  You can always use the interop layers to convert content in stages.

Comment: I am converting a Winform application with MVP architecture to WPF. Of course, MVP in this case is utilizing events in Winform. And after I've read your blog, I cannot find any reason that we need to change the event-driven architecture to MVVM. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Thomas You don't need to change it - WPF will work this way.  You'll find that, over time, it's often more effective to change it, though.  Being event driven everywhere makes WPF less flexible and a bit more rigid, but is often easier for the transition...

Answer (score 1):

Its not like converting vb.net to C# or something, WPF is a totally different way of writing windows apps.

However, if you have your code cleanly abstracted, and/or your UI code separated from logic, you shouldn't have too much trouble *porting* it to WPF.

WPF also does have the [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) class. Here is a Walkthrough on [Hosting a windows forms control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to rewrite quite a lot. And it's definitely worth doing to take advantage of MVVM.