# Convert csproj file from winform to wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a Winform app that has one very simple form, a program.cs main file and about 60 back-end .cs files. I want to convert the project to a WPF application. Looking [here](https://www.google.ca/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=convert%20form%20to%20wpf%20site%3astackoverflow.com&safe=off) didn't show anything close to what I want to do.

I need to

- Convert the csproj file so it will allow me to add WPF windows
- That conversion to be done "in place" to keep my source control tidy and avoid the trouble of adding back all the back end files in their proper folders, add the references to external dependencies, etc.
- Create one empty mainwindow.xaml (+.cs) file that I will manually fill with the appropriate controls.

Then, I will manually split the content of the old forms file between the view and the viewmodel files.

Any way of doing that easier than starting from scratch?

EDIT: I would rather not host the new WPF ui into the old winforms shell but replace the current forms application by a wpf one.

EDIT2: I **do not** want to convert the entire project and the architecture to WPF (as it was asked and answered several times on SO), I totally understand that these are 2 different framework and I am totally willing to do the change manually. I want to convert the **csproj** so it will compile as a WPF app instead of a Forms app.

Comment: Anything related with **coding** ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685142/mixing-wpf-with-a-winform-application

Comment: I would definitely start from scratch. If the logic is that common, you could make the "back-end" files their own assembly. This is defintiley about programming, if not coding though.

Comment: @Alexei: From the FAQ:"With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." My understanding is that configuring your visual studio project to build an application is "programming" isn't it? Or should convert the project to a makefile and then as a question about it?

Comment: I believe this is on-topic, and the answer is, "start over, there's no conversion available".

Comment: @VincentHubert I'm not sure why you addressed your comment to me - it was not clear if your question is duplicate of "use WPF in WinForms" or not - so you edit made clear that you want conversion (which does not exist in VS) - closed as dup found by icemanind.

Comment: This [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652000/winform-conversion-to-wpf) should answer your question.

Comment: @Alexei, Well, as you correctly guessed, you were not the intended recipient. Comment should have gone to L.B.

Comment: Try creating an empty Winforms project, then creating an empty WPF project, then comparing the two project files.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I did quite like that, and it worked. How do I get this question re-opened so I can mark that answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from your edit2 that you just want to change the project type from "Winforms" to "WPF" without changing any of the project items. I don't know why you want to do this, but try creating an empty Winforms project, then creating an empty WPF project, then comparing the two project files.

Whatever the difference is between the two empty projects, make that change to your existing Winforms project.

Comment: I want to change the project items as well, but that, I *know* how to do it :)

Answer (score 14):

The short answer for those that don't want to do the comparison themselves is that a WPF .csproj file contains an addition property:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Just put that in the first `<PropertyGroup>...</PropertyGroup>` section, it shouldn't matter where.

The meaning of `{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548}` is that this is a WPF project, and `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` indicates a C# project.  You can learn more about project type guids from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802198/3010454).

Comment: @digitlworld I agree. I can't delete mine because it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SDK project format enable WPF using the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```